# Analysis of how one variable explains residuals

Tags: r, residuals, lm

I have run an lm in R and extracted the residuals, say:

```
fit <- lm(size~metric,data=db)
fit.res <- residuals(fit)
```

How can I now analyse if the residuals can be explained by a different variable of the dataset so I can state that “`metric` does not explain `size` measurements properly because does not include a certain variable”. In other words, how could I analyse if the reason of the bad fit is that one variable, for instance, `nitrogen`, was not included?

```
lm(fit.res ~ db$nitrogen)
```

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "metric does not fit", but if you want to be sure that some variable is not related to residuals, why do you not simply include it in your first regression in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps my edits make things clearer?

Comment: To expand on @ChristophHanck's comment: Typically, you would use something like `fit <- lm(size ~ metric * nitrogen, data = db); anova(fit)`.